# Crystal Reports: using date from the datatime field as a parameter

Tags: crystal-reports

I am working on a report that I need to add a date range parameter. The field that I need to use in the datetime field, and I need to use the date portion from the field. I tried using the following, but the report returns no result.

```
cast(StartDateTime as date) between {?StartDate} and {?EndDate}
```

For the time being, I am using the Select Expert to sort the date range, but I have to manually enter the date in 'yyyy-mm-dd' format. Is there a way to set up the parameter, so that I can use the calendar to choose the dates?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use one parameter field and set it to range and date instead of two.
With this you can use easily this formula:

`{StartDateTime} = {?Parameter}`

If you set the Parameter to Date instead of DateTime it will automatically check with the start of the day for the first range and the end of the day for the last range.